# Unable to post data to Firebase Database from Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase for my chat app for Android platform. I'm using this library for Firebase Database:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.0'
```

I followed all the steps from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/) to setup my project. I set `true` for both `read` and `write` permission for my Firebase Database.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

I'm using the following code to post my data to Firebase Database (*following block of code triggers  once a button clicked*):

```
String name = loyalUserText.getText().toString().trim();

FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference dbRef = db.getReference().child("name");
dbRef.setValue(name);
Log.e(TAG, "onClick: "+dbRef.toString());
```

And my log returns this:

```
 E/LoginActivity: onClick:https://poztal-14f48.firebaseio.com/name
```

Then I checked my Firebase Database and there is no entry. It looks empty. I created a child with the same child name(`"name"`) and I added a new value into it.

But this value is not reflecting into my app with `ValueEventListener`. The problem is my app is not communicating with firebase database.

**Update:**

The listener I implemented in my activity is `OnCompleteListener<Void>`:

```
dbRef.setValue(name).addOnCompleteListener(this);

@Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onComplete: " + task.isComplete());
        Log.e(TAG, "onComplete: " + task.toString());
    }
```

and this `onComplete()` block was not reached.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check for error using on completion Listener and update the question

Comment: @NishantDubey I've updated my question. please look into it.

Comment: This is not how you add completion callback

Comment: 'ref.setValue("I'm writing data", new Firebase.CompletionListener() { @Override public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) { if (firebaseError != null) { System.out.println("Data could not be saved. " + firebaseError.getMessage()); } else { System.out.println("Data saved successfully."); } }' this is what I meant

Comment: I want the output of **firebaseError.getMessage()**

Comment: Add a [listener for connection state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state) to confirm that you have a connection to the Firebase servers.

Answer (score 1):

Please use pojo class to set your value into firebase database like below.

```
String name = loyalUserText.getText().toString().trim();
User user = new User();
user.setName(name);
FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference dbRef = db.getReference().child("name");

dbRef.setValue(user);
```

Comment: I tried using pojo class too but it doesn't solve's my problem.

Comment: @Madhan did you use firebase auth or not ?

Comment: I'm not using auth, and i changed default permission into true for both read and write.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to insert `[NAME]` against field named `name`, try `Map`.

```
Map<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
param.put("name", loyalUserText.getText().toString().trim());

Firebase reference = new Firebase(YOUR_FIREBASE_URL);
reference.push().setValue(param);
```